# Japanese character entry in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, internationalization

I'm currently working on a Silverlight solution that accepts Unicode characters and displays these correctly, however the text boxes don't seem to accept foreign characters such as Japanese (I'm trying Hiragana at the moment) and Chinese. These can be copied from the clipboard however when changing the language bar in Windows these characters cannot be entered. Is this a common problem and how should this be handled?

Any help much appreciated